# I want to convert my view as it is in the picture to a downloadable pdf file in mvc, c#, or JS

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

[This]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW04g.png)  is my view. After the button click, I want to embed this view as a picture or by HTML with CSS to a pdf file. This pdf file gets downloaded on button click.I tried lots of methods like itextsharp, jsPDF, phantomJS but I still have no clue how to achieve it. Can anyone help?

```js
       function start() {
           var table = tableToJson($('#StudentInfoListTable').get(0))
           var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a1', true);
           doc.cellInitialize();
           $.each(table, function (i, row) {
               $.each(row, function (j, cell) {
                   doc.cell(10, 50, 120, 50, cell, i);  // 2nd parameter=top margin,1st=left margin 3rd=row cell width 4th=Row height
               })
           })
           doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
       }

       function tableToJson(table) {
           var data = [];

           // first row needs to be headers
           var headers = [];
           for (var i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
               headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace('/ /gi', '');
           }


           // go through cells
           for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {

               var tableRow = table.rows[i];
               var rowData = {};

               for (var j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {

                   rowData[headers[j]] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;

               }

               data.push(rowData);
           }

           return data;
}
```

```css
body{
background: url("");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 400px;
        }

        .box-header {
            background-color: #838060;
            height: 50px;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            color: white;
        }

            .box-header h4 {
                position: relative;
                top: 10px;
            }

        .box {
            background-color: whitesmoke;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            font-size:28px;
        }
        .middle{
            width:200px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table cellpadding="30" class="table table-striped" id="StudentInfoListTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="@Model.img" alt="" height="200" width="200" /></td>
                                <td class="middle"></td>
                                <td>LICENSE ID - @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LicenseID)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>NAME: </td>
                                <td class="middle"></td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Relo) </td>
                                <td class="middle"></td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.careOf)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>GENDER: </td>
                                <td class="middle"></td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.gender)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>BLOOD GROUP: </td>
                                <td class="middle"></td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.blood)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>DATE OF BIRTH: </td>
                                <td class="middle"></td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.date)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>CONTACT NO: </td>
                                <td class="middle"></td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Mobile)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>ADDRESS: </td>
                                <td class="middle"></td>
                                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Address)</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Signature </td>
                                <td class="middle"></td>
                                <td><img src="@Model.sign" alt="" style="background-color:white;"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br/><br/>
                        <button onclick="start()" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">download</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Tried this way but doesn't render the CSS, instead it generates this  [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIb44.png).

Comment: Nowhere in your code you are exporting css. You are only exporting data.

Comment: how to do it in a correct way. can you guide, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can Post the HTML string to server and convert it to PDF.

Here is the demo :

HTML : (Obviously you can use your existing HTML)

```
<div id="dvTable">
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 120px;background-color:#D20B0C">
                Customer Id
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 150px;background-color:#D20B0C">
                Name
            </th>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 100px;background-color:#D20B0C">
                Country
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                ALFKI
            </td>
            <td>
                Maria Anders
            </td>
            <td>
                Germany
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                ANATR
            </td>
            <td>
                Ana Trujillo
            </td>
            <td>
                Mexico
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hfTableHTML" name="Table_HTML" />
<hr />
<asp:Button Text="Export" runat="server" OnClick="Export" OnClientClick="SetHTML()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetHTML() {
        document.getElementById("hfTableHTML").value = document.getElementById("dvTable").innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

Namespaces:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
```

C# function:

```
protected void Export(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Export HTML String as PDF.
    string html = Request.Form["Table_HTML"];
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(html);
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Table.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

OR For MVC/C# you can use : Rotativa http://nuget.org/packages/Rotativa. It's based on wkhtmltopdf.

install it from nuget : Install-Package Rotativa -Version 1.7.3 and usage is simple :

```
public ActionResult PrintIndex()
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = "Giorgio" }) { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
}
```

You can define an action that returns an ActionResult of the type ActionAsPdf (RouteAsPdf is also available). where name = "Giorgio" is a route parameter.

Comment: thank you. I got a clear understanding of your code.

Comment: <asp:Button Text="Export" runat="server" OnClick="Export" OnClientClick="SetHTML()" />    can this line be converted to Razor code?